# Oracle: idle_time appears to be ignored

Tags: oracle, session, session-timeout

In my understanding, creating a profile with the `idle_time` set to a certain value (in minutes) and creating a user with this profile should force the `SNIPED` status for that user's session in case he is idle for longer than `idle_time`. When the user tries to execute a query after this has happened, he receives a message that he  must connect again.

**First question: Is that right?** If so, read on:

I'm running a test script as follows in sqlplus (without the placeholders obviously):

```
connect system/<password>@<tns>
CREATE PROFILE test_profile LIMIT idle_time 1;
CREATE USER test_user PROFILE test_profile IDENTIFIED BY test_user;
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO test_user;
GRANT ALTER SESSION TO test_user;
GRANT SELECT ON <schema>.<table> TO test_user;
disconnect;
connect test_user/test_user@<tns>
SELECT * FROM <schema>.<table>;
```

Everything works up to this point; the sqlplus window is still open. Now I open an additional sqplus window and connect using the system account, running the following query after doing other stuff for a while:

```
SELECT username, status, seconds_in_wait FROM v$session WHERE username = 'test_user';
```

I get something like:

```
USERNAME  STATUS   SECONDS_IN_WAIT
--------- -------- ---------------
TEST_USER INACTIVE            1166
```

**Why has the status not been set to `SNIPED`?**

Obviously, If I run another query from the test_user's sqlplus window, I do not get a message asking me to reconnect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the database's `RESOURCE_LIMIT` parameter to `TRUE` in order for resource limits in profiles to take effect.  Assuming you use a spfile (otherwise omit the `scope = BOTH` part)

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET resource_limit = TRUE scope = BOTH
```

Once you do that, `PMON` should start sniping the sessions that have exceeded your `IDLE_TIME` when it wakes up every few minutes.